# I cant print horizontally

Tags: python, printing

I want to make a book catalog, the output is to print horizontally and change line for every 3 books. I understand that we can do a print horizontal by using:

```
end = ""
```

BUT that only works for 1 line. As my output has 3 line like Title, ISBN, Price, if I using end = "", it can't get it done.

Below is my code

```
line_format = "{:50s} \n{:6s} - {:13s} \n{:11s}"
    books = db.get_books(kel)
    for book in books:
        print((line_format.format(str(book.title),
                                 str(book.isbn),
                                 "Rp. {:,}".format(book.price).replace(",","."))))
```

What I got is:

```
Deaver - Never Game  A/UK                          
9780008303778 
Rp. 161.000
Poirot - DEATH ON THE NILE (Exp]                   
9780008328948 
Rp. 28.000 
Alchemist - 25th Anniv ed                          
9780062355300 
Rp. 160.000
Finn- Woman in the Window [MTI]                    
9780062906137 
Rp. 162.000
Mahurin- Blood & Honey                             
9780063041172 
Rp. 62.000
```

What I want for the output is:

```
Deaver - Never Game     DEATH ON THE NILE (Exp]  Alchemist                          
9780008303778           9780008328948            9780062355300 
Rp. 161.000             Rp. 28.000               Rp. 160.000

Woman in the Window     Blood & Honey
9780062906137           9780063041172 
Rp. 162.000             Rp. 62.000
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Please work through one or two tutorials on output formatting.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: I have revised my question, hopefully it is acceptable now. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Note that you will not "find an answer" on line.  Simple columnar formatting of output is not common enough, nor difficult enough, that people post specific solutions.  You need to review the principles of data organization and output, and craft your custom solution.  Look up how to "chunk" data.  You need to chunk each of your lists into groups of 3, and then print out those chunks in the desired order.  You will need list slicing and loop control.